# How to unit test a socket.io middleware that works with cookies

Tags: node.js, cookies, socket.io

I am working with sessions, and i have a middleware that parse the request's cookies.

I am unit testing my middlewares, but i don't see how to deal with this one (how to insert a cookie so i can assert its presence into the middleware).

I tried to use the `supertest` library, calling a route that insert a cookie before connecting socket.io, but the cookie is not here when the middleware is fired (which make sense since the cookies are stored into the browser, and my unit tests are launched with mocha).

Do you know a way to test this kind of use case ?

Comment: It makes me very surprised that this question receives so little attention (no upvotes (besides mine), no answers, no comments at all). I'm having exactly the same issue: need to test socket.io connection with cookies. This task seems so common to me, and I found almost nothing on the subject. Very little people use socket.io in this way? Or those who do, don't care about tests? Quite strange to me..

Comment: Not quite a solution to test socket.io with cookies, but a solution to test socket.io with passport.socketio (which uses cookies) : http://dmitryfrank.com/articles/socketio_passport_testing

Answer (score 0):

the socket.io library handles all the cookie parsing and it is extensively tested. You shouldnt need to test generic cookie handling, but only that your specific middleware does a specific thing with a specific cookie. Towards these ends, you can just ensure whatever stand-in for a socket object you pass to your middleware during testing has a `client.cookie` property and then make sure your output is what you expect.